# Unable to inject NotifierService in a Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying inject Angular NotifierService in my service class , so that in case of any exception from service side, i can show error notification.

I tried to inject a bean of NotifierService in constructor of my service class, but its showing undefiend.

Could you help me how to fix this issue.

in app.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService{

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,private notifyService:NotifierService) {

    }
.......

handleError(error) {
        let errorMessage = '';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // Get client-side error
            errorMessage = error.error.message;
        } else {
            // Get server-side error
            errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
        }
        this.notifyService.notify('error', 'Internal Server error please contact Admin!!');//undefined
        return throwError(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

In app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NotifierModule.withConfig(Constant.customNotifierOptions),
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [NotifierService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class ClaimDetailsModule { }
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'notify' of undefined
    at CatchSubscriber.handleError [as selector] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:2142:30)
```

Comment: That's just an unused constructor parameter, **not** a [parameter property](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties).

Comment: Maybe just the missing `private` modifier in the constructor?

Comment: @ChrisY still error occurring when I added private

Comment: @JobyWilsonMathews: check my update answer. There is still a typo :D

Answer (score -1):

It's a typo as you are injecting `notifyService` and then using `this.notifier` :) , try

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient,private notifier :NotifierService)
```

or

```
this.notifyService.notify('error', 'Internal Server error please contact Admin!!')
```

###Update 1:

There is again a typo:

```
this.notify=notifyService;
```

and you are calling

```
this.notifier.notify();
```

correct it to

```
this.notify.notify();
```

**OR** in constructor , correct the variable name

```
this.notifier = notifyService
```

###Update 2:

Try creating the `NotifierService` at root level and removed from `providers: [NotifierService]` of module.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotifierService
```

Comment: While coping the code to SO , the name got changed sorry. I corrected the question. Still error is occurring

Comment: I have the same error, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @JFouad Try Update 2 and let me know